# How to change XHR Request URL path of a page sending xhr request using javascript after page loads using curl & php?

Tags: php, ajax, curl, xmlhttprequest

I am using php and curl to get source code of a web page.
So i created a curl code in php to get the source code of web page ( suppose example.com ).

But this web page sends an **XHR Request** That changes the source code using javascript.
This XHR Request URL should look like : https://example.com/test.php

But when i use curl to get the source of web page in localhost this XHR Request URL changes to: https://localhost/test.php

And even if i upload it on a server it replaces localhost by my domain name but i want it as it is with example.com
How can i do that ? Also i do not have access to example.com

Comment: There's no *trivial*, *general* way to find all the URLs generated via JS and rewrite them and, even if you did, it would almost certainly fail due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).